# How to put code with minted in the margin?

Tags: minted, marginpar

[image]how to put code with the package minted in the margin (marginpar did not work)?
I want my code in the marge like the document but  I want use the package minted.
Thank you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}   % for margin note
\usepackage{marginnote} % for margin note
\usepackage{minted}     % for highlighted code

\begin{document}
    \marginnote{  %this should appear in the margin (doesn't work)
    \begin{minted}{python}
        import numpy as np

        def incmatrix(genl1,genl2):
        m = len(genl1)
        n = len(genl2)
        M = None #to become the incidence matrix
        VT = np.zeros((n*m,1), int)  #dummy variable

        #compute the bitwise xor matrix
        M1 = bitxormatrix(genl1)
        M2 = np.triu(bitxormatrix(genl2),1) 
    \end{minted}}

    \begin{minted}{python} % this correctly appears in the document
        import numpy as np

        def incmatrix(genl1,genl2):
        m = len(genl1)
        n = len(genl2)
        M = None #to become the incidence matrix
        VT = np.zeros((n*m,1), int)  #dummy variable

        #compute the bitwise xor matrix
        M1 = bitxormatrix(genl1)
        M2 = np.triu(bitxormatrix(genl2),1) 
    \end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

`marginnote`s don't seem to like having code like `minted` inside. Also the code is way too large to fit in the page's  margin, unless you reduce the text width by at least half.

A workaround could be to combine `wrapfigure` and `minipage`s as follows, so you don't have to sacrifice the document's width over the whole page, but just where the code appears.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}    
\usepackage{minted}     
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\linewidth}
    \hspace{-2.8cm}
    \begin{minipage}[h]{\linewidth}
    \begin{minted}{python}
        import numpy as np

        def incmatrix(genl1,genl2):
        m = len(genl1)
        n = len(genl2)
        M = None #to become the incidence matrix
        VT = np.zeros((n*m,1), int)  #dummy variable

        #compute the bitwise xor matrix
        M1 = bitxormatrix(genl1)
        M2 = np.triu(bitxormatrix(genl2),1) 
    \end{minted}
    \end{minipage}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Superuser27 for this answer.

Comment: @FM you're welcome :) remember to mark an answer as "accepted" if the solution works for you, by clicking on the green check mark